# new value not assigned to id or class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, countdown

The below script is for displaying countdown timing

Used code is here with a combination of php,javascript

Tried many ways but no use

```
 <script>
            function countdown(endT,callback,val) {
            var val,days,hours,minutes,sec,timer;

            end = new Date(endT);

            end = end.getTime(); //Get initial Date in Milliseconds,
            if (isNaN(end)) {
               alert('@ countdown.js @  "Invalid Date", valid format- mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss TT ');
               return;
            }

            timer = setInterval(calculate,1000);//Timer to calculate remaining time

            function calculate(){
             var current = new Date();
             var remaining = parseInt((end - current.getTime())/1000);//remaining seconds, 

                if (remaining <= 0){
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    days=0;
                    hours=0;
                    minutes=0;
                    sec=0;
                    display(days,hours,minutes,sec);
                    if (typeof callback === 'function' ) {
                        callback();
                    }

                }else{

                    days = parseInt(remaining/86400);
                    remaining = (remaining%86400);
                    hours = parseInt(remaining/3600);
                    remaining = (remaining%3600);
                    minutes = parseInt(remaining/60);
                    remaining = (remaining%60);
                    sec = parseInt(remaining);
                    display(days,hours,minutes,sec);


                }
            }

            //Function For displaying Results in HTML page with specific ID's 
            function display(days,hours,minutes,sec) {

                var dl = days.toString().length;
                if (dl == "1") {
                    sl = 2;
                }else{
                    if (isNaN(dl)) {
                        sl = 3;
                    }
                    sl = dl;
                }
                d1="days";
                d2=val;
                d=d1.concat(d2);

                h1="hours";
                h2=val;
                h=h1.concat(h2);

                m1="minutes";
                m2=val;
                m=m1.concat(m2);

                s1="seconds";
                s2=val;
                s=s1.concat(s2);

                document.getElementById(d).innerHTML = ("00"+days).slice(-sl);
                document.getElementById(h).innerHTML = ("0"+hours).slice(-2);
                document.getElementById(m).innerHTML = ("0"+minutes).slice(-2);
                document.getElementById(s).innerHTML = ("0"+sec).slice(-2);
            }

        }

    </script>
    <?php
    for ($i = 6; $i <9; $i++) 
    {
    $dates="2019-03-0$i 12:45:01";
    ?>

        <script>
        countdown('<?php echo $dates;?>',callback,'<?php echo $i;?>');
    function callback(){
          //alert('Your Id is Expired');
    };

    </script>


    <div class="countDown" align="center">
                               <span id="days<?php echo $i; ?>">00</span>     <!-- Remaining Days,id="days"-->
                               <span id="hours<?php echo $i; ?>">00</span>    <!-- Remaining hours ,id="hours"-->
                               <span id="minutes<?php echo $i; ?>">00</span>  <!-- Remaining minutes,id="minutes"-->
                               <span id="seconds<?php echo $i; ?>">00</span>  <!-- Remaining secounds,id="secounds"-->
                            </div>
                            <?php
    }
    ?>
```

First iterated value only assigned to all other loop ids...Instead of unique values

Loop have 3 iterations

First iteration value assigned first id

The first iteration value assigned to next two iterations..

Kindly help me to fix the issue..

Answer (score -1):

Combination of php and javascript always confusing. It can be used in combination when creating dynamic elements on page load but not after page load.So you have to code in javascript for countdown. If there is need to access server variable (i.e php variable ) then you need `Ajax` request to access this variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, If you feel comfortable try to let me know how to implement what you said...